# Observable.map() is not called

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm usin RxJava and RxAndroid and I just start study about them yesterday. I fetch data from server using REST api. I use two main Rx operators, one is `.map()` and another is `.zip()`.

The following code is one of my `Observable`

```
protected static Observable<List<Subdistrict>> subdistrictObservable = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<String>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<String> call() {
        try {
            return Observable.just(new MasterService.MasterSubdistrict().get());
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
})
        .filter(new Func1<String, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(String s) {
                return s != null;
            }
        })
        .map(new Func1<String, List<Subdistrict>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Subdistrict> call(String s) {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                List<Subdistrict> subdistricts = null;

                try {
                    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(s);
                    node = node.get("json");

                    TypeReference<List<Subdistrict>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<Subdistrict>>() {
                    };
                    subdistricts = mapper.readValue(node.toString(), typeRef);
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }

                return subdistricts;
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

And zip multiple `Observable` together

```
Observable<List<Region>> observableChain = Observable.zip(
        Subdistrict.subdistrictObservable,
        District.districtObservable,
        Province.provinceObservable,
        Region.regionObservable,
        new Func4<List<Subdistrict>, List<District>, List<Province>, List<Region>, List<Region>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Region> call(List<Subdistrict> subdistricts, List<District> districts, List<Province> provinces, List<Region> regions) {
                List<Region> zipRegions = new LinkedList<Region>();
                // Do my stuff

                return zipRegions;

            }
        });
observableChain
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(regionOnNext);
```

The problem is `.map()` in the `Observable` is not called. I dont know why.

Comment: Try debugging individual observables without `zip` first. If one of them completes without emitting any items, zip will complete without items as well not waiting for others.

Comment: I tried and only `.just()` is called. The follow operators does not be called. @YaroslavStavnichiy

Comment: You are using schedulers, tasks are executed in background. Do you wait enough time in your main thread for tasks to complete, or you just exit immediately after `subscribe`?

Comment: Do consider what @YaroslavStavnichiy has mentioned - simple way is to add something like `Observable.timer(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toBlocking().subscribe();` at the end of main method. Also, try debugging by adding `.doOnNext` at multiple conjunctions and see if items are emitted.

Comment: I found that `MasterService.MasterSubdistrict()` does not be called. The `MasterSubdistrict()` is a class extends `Asynctask`. Do you have any idea  why it is not be called? @YaroslavStavnichiy @PavanKumar

Comment: @PandarianLd It is about the same. Have you tried all the ideas mentioned above?

Comment: Currently I found that it's my fault. When I get a result `String` from `Asynctask`, I does not call `.execute()` (/A\)... @YaroslavStavnichiy@PavanKumar

Comment: FYI, `new MasterService.MasterSubdistrict().get()` for `just()` is not in rx world, it's creation of observable. If you want to do AsyncTask in rx world, use `fromEmitter` and do async task inside it.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider that . @ytRino

Comment: @ytRino Could you please give an example of how to call AsyncTask with `fromEmitter` and handle its result (the String returned from the API)

Answer (score 0):

I follow what @ytRino suggested by using `fromEmitter` and it works. However, I'm not sure whether it's correct or not. So if anyone found fault(s) in the following code, please told me.

The following code is a works version of `Observable`. I add a abstract class called `MasterService.Callback` so when the `Asynctask` finish execute, the result will be returned to `Observable`.

```
protected static Observable<List<Subdistrict>> subdistrictObservable = Observable.fromEmitter(new Action1<AsyncEmitter<List<Subdistrict>>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(final AsyncEmitter<List<Subdistrict>> listAsyncEmitter) {
        try {

            new MasterService.MasterSubdistrict(new MasterService.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String s) {
                    List<Subdistrict> subdistricts = null;
                    // Do something
                    listAsyncEmitter.onNext(subdistricts);
                    listAsyncEmitter.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNull() {
                    listAsyncEmitter.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    listAsyncEmitter.onError(t);
                }
            }).execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            listAsyncEmitter.onError(e);
        }
    }
}, AsyncEmitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```